# What software tool allows you to create an installation disk for windows xp from your installed xp?

Tags: windows

Which softwares allow you to create an installation disk for windows xp from your installed xp? (Without needing to have an installation disk)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  Many components needed to install Windows XP, most importantly the [Windows Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Setup) application itself, are not transferred to the hard drive during installation.

Answer (score 1):

If disk image - not installation CD - is enough, you can use for example Norton Ghost to create it. You can do that to external USB disk, network disk, Ghost server or another harddisk (or another partition in same hard disk). [Partimage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) is free software having about same functionality.

When that disk image is installed to another computer, it includes exactly the same drivers, serial number and so on. So you can't move it to whatever hardware (Windows can't always install new drivers, sometimes it just crashes).

Also, before creating that image you should use [sysprep](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577) to enable installation wizard for new installations (that way you can enter correct serial number for each installation).